# Canvas - Cannot create image url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I set up a fiddle with two images. I don't understand why image A) is not suitable, to me the source looks similar to the source of image B).

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AYE5c/)

HTML

```
A)<img src="http://img.ui-portal.de/uim/Coop/monster-beratung_140x115.jpg" />

  B)<img src="http://i0.gmx.net/images/258/18821258,pd=2,h=250,mxh=600,mxw=800,w=480.jpg"  />


    <h4> Display images above with dataURL as source: </h4>

        <div id="converted" ></div>
```

JS

```
//create canvas-image from A)

var imgA = new Image();

imgA.crossOrigin = "anonymous"; 

imgA.src = "http://img.ui-portal.de/uim/Coop/monster-beratung_140x115.jpg";

            imgA.onload = function(){

            var canvasA = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvasA.width = imgA.width;
            canvasA.height = imgA.height;
            var ctxA = canvasA.getContext('2d');
            ctxA.drawImage(imgA, 0, 0);
            var imgURl = canvasA.toDataURL();
                console.log("die url: "+ imgURl)
                $("#converted").append("<img src="+imgURl +" />");
            }


 //create canvas-image from B)

var imgB = new Image();

imgB.crossOrigin = "anonymous"; 

imgB.src = "http://i0.gmx.net/images/258/18821258,pd=2,h=250,mxh=600,mxw=800,w=480.jpg";

            imgB.onload = function(){

            var canvasB = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvasB.width = imgB.width;
            canvasB.height = imgB.height;
            var ctxB = canvasB.getContext('2d');
            ctxB.drawImage(imgB, 0, 0);
            var imgURl = canvasB.toDataURL();
                console.log("die url: "+ imgURl)
                $("#converted").append("<img src="+imgURl +" />");
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first image is protected by Owner.

see debuger message

```
Image from origin 'http://img.ui-portal.de' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin
Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the   
requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: where can I find the debugger message in Chrome?

Comment: hit `F12` and then `Esc` or click on `Console` tab.